# Ansible Error : The lxc module is not importable. Check the requirements

Tags: ansible, devops

My task looks something like this

```
- name: Create a started container
    lxc_container:
      name: test-container-started
      container_log: true
      template: ubuntu
      state: started
      template_options: --release trusty
```

I get the following errors:

```
> TASK: [lxc | Create a started container]
> **************************************  failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
> BECOME-SUCCESS-azsyqtknxvlowmknianyqnmdhuggnanw failed=True msg='The
> lxc module is not importable. Check the requirements.' The lxc module
> is not importable. Check the requirements.
> 
> 
> FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but you have accepted incorrect answer as solution for your question. The correct one is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39541825/6841451

Answer (score 4):

If you use Debian or Ubuntu as host system there is already `python-lxc` package available. The best way to install it is Ansible of course, just before `lxc_container` tasks:

```
  tasks:

    - name: Install provisioning dependencies
      apt: name=python-lxc

    - name: Create docker1.lxc container
      lxc_container:
        name: docker1
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue andI solved it by making sure to `pip install lxc-python2` system-wide on the target machine.

In my case the target was localhost via an `ansible_connection=local` host and I thought I could get away with `pip: name=lxc-python2`, but that installed into my current virtualenv.

Comment: There is no need to install (system-wide) libs to target host to get this working. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39541825/6841451

Answer (score 0):

lxc_container is relatively new. 
To run the lxc_container module you need to make sure the pip package is installed on the target host, as well as lxc.

e.g

```
pip install lxc-python2
apt-get install lxc
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed since the answers were given and it took me a day to figure out how this works now in 2024.
Not a word on this in the ansible lxc_container doc page so I decided to add this here.

bindings to lxc in python3 are done by lxc module. you simply install it with pip and you are good to go.
If you are like me and steal shamelessly examples of lxc ansible scripture from the interpipes you may need another fix however. The one I used (and I saw others like it so you may have the same problem) have "*become=true*" clause which makes it being run as root. Modern lxc however runs in user space so if you are like me and you installed your python3 lxc module as well as ansible in your user account then this will not work. I removed that and it all worked like a charm (well not really but the "*lxc module is not importable*" thing was gone and specific to my own needs so I skip them here).

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer to the issue is to add:
`become: yes`
just before the `lxc_container` -module section, so as to get root privileges to run lxc-commands on target host.

Definitely not is it required to install any python2-lxc -support libs to *target* hosts to use lxc_container module, which requires such support to be available in management host only. Only the python2 must be available in the target host to be usable with current Ansible versions.

See ansible documention for more info about the requirements about the  [lxc-container module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lxc_container_module.html): (on host that executes module)

- lxc >= 1.0 # OS package
- python >= 2.6 # OS Package
- lxc-python2 >= 0.1 # PIP Package from https://github.com/lxc/python2-lxc