# How to create lxc containers in ubuntu 14.04 using Ansible module?

Tags: ansible, lxc, devops

I am trying to create a lxc container by using lxc_container module provided by ansible. Can someone tell me the exact playbook task which will just create the lxc container ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for creating a [Ansible playbook](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html) and the [Ansible LXC module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lxc_container_module.html)?

Comment: yes i had.. and nope it didn't help... basically throws something like

failed=True msg='The lxc module is not importable. Check the requirements.' The lxc module is not importable.

Comment: What's the output of `python --version && python -c 'import lxc; exit();'`?

Comment: if your getting an error about no module lxc then follow up with the answers outlined in the [Ansible Error : The lxc module is not importable. Check the requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051734/ansible-error-the-lxc-module-is-not-importable-check-the-requirements) answer since this is a duplicate of their question.

Comment: yes i know & its asked by me .. the answer didn't worked ..

Comment: Output for your question :
Python 2.7.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lxc

Comment: No module named lxc. thus python does not have the lxc module installed and would need to be installed either by your package manager or by pip.

Comment: My answer to your issue is below. However, please in the future be more descriptive in your postings. Stating X is broken how to fix X does not help us to help you. We need to know the error messages that are coming up and what steps you took to encounter the error along with log outputs. These three things are also the same items you would need to debug your own errors.

Comment: sure mate, thanks for the efforts

Comment: No worries. Also, If the answer below helped then please click the check mark to accept the answer and don't forget to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response in the comments above and your duplicate question.

It would appear that your issue is caused by not having the module lxc-python2 installed.

I'm also assuming there's other errors which your are overlooking in your posts and debugging efforts. So the steps to apply are as follows:

1. `sudo apt-get install python-pip`
2. `pip install lxc-python2`
3. *read any error output carefully.*